# Typescript infer method return type and apply it to property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this class:

```
class Element<T extends IElement = {}> {
    thisIsAProp:T;
    renderResult:string = null;
    render() {
        return "thing";
    }
}

class NewElement extends Element {
    render() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Internally, when `render()` is called, its result is stored in `renderResult`. The problem is that I want `renderResult` to be the type of the `render()` return value. As you can see, in `NewElement` the return type is a number, so I want `renderResult` to be a number. I've tried this:

```
class Element<T extends IElement = {}, R extends string|number = null> {
    thisIsAProp:T;
    renderResult:R = null;
    render():R {
        return "thing";
    }
}

class NewElement extends Element {
    render() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to infer the `render()` type to the generic `R` (like you do with `function<X>(arg:X):X`) and apply that generic to the `renderResult` property, but I'm not able to achieve it. It throws in `Element.render()`:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'. 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'R', but 'R' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'
```

and in `NewElement.render()`:

```
Property 'render' in type 'NewElement' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Element<null>'. Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => null'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

So, essentially, is not picking the `render()` return type and applying it to R, but trying to apply `R` to the `render()` return type. I'm a bit lost here as I cannot add the `infer` keyword anywhere to force it to infer the return type to `R`.

Another thing I want is to keep the default generic values, to avoid adding `Element<X, Y>` all around the code.

Comment: I don't think you can do this *without* passing the type parameters for <T,R>. When you tell TS that a function returns R, it won't try to override that return type. Consider the case `new Element<{}, number>()`: the `render` function will be incompatible with the newly-created Element instance type. this is separate from the classes that extend your `Element`. Maybe you could create an abstract class with an abstract `render` method instead?

Comment: Oh @Badashi, I also thought that I was trying something impossible. I'm gonna try with an abstract method to see if I can achieve something. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't really make sense - if `Element.render` returns a string, then subclasses' `render` methods must also return strings, otherwise they violate the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @kaya3 well, in this case makes sense for me. Is not the first time a type is a union, mixin or something like that and you do typeofs and whatevers to work differently depending on the union type you are working on (for example, tell that to react render where you can return a react component or a react fragment). Is what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: It doesn't make sense "for you", because Typescript will raise a compile-time error regardless of who wrote the code. It is a compile-time error to override a method with a new return type which is not assignable to the old return type. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @kaya3 "Typescript will raise a compile-time error" and this is what I'm trying to avoid. I don't see any problem in having a mutable variable which can only have 2 defined types, like a union. In Typescript is possible to define a function that will return different types, so I don't see this any different from that. Is a method that can return different types, the same way a function can return different types. What yo do with these types you return is on your own. I just want to pre-catch those types as they are known beforehand instead of just returning a union and doing "typeof" elsewhere

Comment: If `Element.render` returns `string` then a subclass's `render` method cannot return `number`. This is an immutable fact and there is no way to avoid it; no clever use of generics will make it not an error. If one `render` method does not return a subtype of the other, then the class cannot be a subclass of the other.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh, ok, this throws a bit of light. If I define an abstract render that could return both? the abstract is returning an union and any implementation of that abstract method should return a subtype of the render type. What I'm looking is taking something like this `function m<T extends string|number>(arg:T) { return arg} let a = m("asd"); let b = a.substring(1); let n = m(123); let nn = n.toFixed(2);` but to other level. As you can see, the result type depends on the _input_, which in the case of a class I want the _input_ to be the render result.